# rails get data from 2 tables with codition

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a site where user can create an account then they can join a club.  My tables are Users, Clubs, and UserClubs.

UserClubs has id, club_id, user_id member_type, and status.  When a user joines a club their initial status is set to pending. I'm trying to list all the users who have joined the current club, and where their status is pending.

On the club show page I can get the uses who are registered in the club but can't figoure out how to loop through only those who are registered in the club with a status pending. If I do this, it will show me the club members:

```
<% if @club.users.empty? %>
  No pend membership request!
<% else %>
  <% @club.users.each do |user| %>
    <%= user.first_name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I can also get the pending users with:

```
@pending = UserClub.where(club_id: @club.id, status: "pending")
```

but I cannot figure out how to do it without doing annother query in each loop. If that is the only way I'll give that a shot but wanted to see if there is a way I can write the query to get the club.users with the club_id and status of pending.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: What version of Rails are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I usually put that in the title.  I’m using rails 6.

Comment: You probably want to use `includes(:users)` in your query: https://bigbinary.com/blog/preload-vs-eager-load-vs-joins-vs-includes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a class method like this in Userclub model.

```
class Userclub < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :club

  def self.pending_users
    pending = where(status: 'pending')
    User.where(id: pending.pluck(:user_id))
  end
end
```

Then you can access thru the query `@club.userclubs.pending_users`

Comment: I added pending_users to the UserClub model changed '@club.userclubs.pending_users' to '@club.user_clubs.pending_users' and it worked.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using Rails 5 or above.

Given `users` and `clubs` tables and models already exist.

Create join table for `clubs` and `users`:

```
rails g migration CreateJoinTableClubUser clubs users
```

Open the just created migration and add `status` field (default 'pending') to `clubs_users` table:

```
class CreateJoinTableClubUser < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_join_table :clubs, :users do |t|
      t.string :status, default: 'pending'
      # t.index [:club_id, :user_id]
      # t.index [:user_id, :club_id]
    end
  end
end
```

Migrate:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Add proper relationship to both `User` and `Club` models:

```
class Club < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
        
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :clubs
end
```

Query:

```
@club.users.where('clubs_users.status = ?','pending')
```

This works for me :)

Comment: Doesn't OP basically already have that with the `UserClubs` table  that is mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

The nicest way would be to call `@club.pending_users`
So the Club class needs an instance method called `pending_users`

```rb
class Club
  def pending_users
    arr = []
    users_clubs.includes(:users).where(status: 'pending').each do |user_club|
      arr << user_club.user
    end
    arr
  end
end
```